# WebCamTexture crashes when I change the scene

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to display telephone camera in two scenes using WebCamTexture but when I load second scene in my android device the game crashes. I've created a plane (as a cinema screen) in front the camera and I've attached this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WebCamTexture mCamera;
    public GameObject plane;

    void Start ()
    {
        plane = GameObject.FindWithTag ("PlayerCam");

        mCamera = new WebCamTexture ();
        plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = mCamera;
        mCamera.Play ();

    }

}
```

In unity editor all works ok, but when I load second scene my android device crashes. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy the WebCamTexture before loading another scene